# No 'Adobe Flash Player' in Software Center

Tags: software-center, video, flash, adobe

I recently switched to Ubuntu and find that I can't watch video on most websites (YouTube is an exception). I've read some tutorials and questions on this site that suggest to just download it from Ubuntu Software, but it can't be found in there.

How would you install Adobe Flash without it and how to even find out if it is already installed?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Firefox 69.0.1 (both 64-bit)

Comment: Have a look at this resource https://itsfoss.com/adobe-alternatives-linux/

Comment: @Graham Thanks. I've checked it out but couldn't find anything about Flash. What did I miss?

Comment: Please check out [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) in the official desktop documentation.

Comment: Adobe Flash Player can't be found in Software Center and it is normal. It only shows snaps packages, flatpak packages if you installed flatpak and deb GRAPHICAL packages. Flash Player isn't really a graphical software but more a plugin.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks! It worked with pepperflash :)

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer: Glad to hear that. Once in a while `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Is the Multiverse repository already enabled? Check in Software and Updates [image: Software and Updates] (the fourth line of repositories). If not, do `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse && sudo apt update` or enable by clicking on it then clicking [Close].

Once Multiverse is enabled, run `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` then close Firefox if it was open.

Relaunch Firefox and go to https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html ; scroll down to section **5. Verify whether Flash Player is installed** . Hit "Activate Adobe Flash" and click on "Allow Now" to enable flash player only for a current website or click "Allow and Remember" to enable Flash Player on all websites.

Do you see animation? If so, it installed OK.

Comment: Hmm, it kinda installed it with bugs. The adobe site views the animation fine, but during the apt-add-repository I get: `Err:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionice Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.194.217 443]`. I might have messed something up when experimenting with the command line. I know for sure that winehq has nothing to do with flash, but for some reason it's causing the error.

Comment: It later says `W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)` a couple of times.

Comment: Typo. I suppose it should be `archive.ubuntu.com`, not `archive.canonical.com`. OTOH, managing package repositories is best done using the _Software & Updates_ tool.

Comment: @Paul Erlenmeyer In your first comment, "bionice" is a typo; try "bionic"

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You mean Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer: No, I meant what I wrote. Note "package _repositories_", not packages.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Alright, I'll have a look at it later.